# Just changed my password on Git and get an error when pushing

Tags: git, gitlab

I just changed my password on git and I am having an error message in the terminal when I try to push

> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.digitas.com/flag/promo-hlgen-alt-7.git/'

I want to know what should I do to update my password from the terminal so I avoid this error.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you use SSH keys for this instead. However, I will help. You just need to run `git config --global credential.helper cache`

To generate SSH keys, see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key)